# Consulta por mês e ano (Php + SQL)

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um sistema em `PHP` no qual utilizo o plugin do datatables, consigo classificar por data, mas o usuário quer estipular o período para consulta, por exemplo:

Selecionar do dia 01/01/2016 até 31/01/2016 e todos os dados desse período serem exibidos.

Tenho que criar os campos para o usuário selecionar o mês de pesquisa desejado e com isso eu preciso criar uma query para cada mês de um determinado ano que o usuário selecionar ou existe outra forma, o que fazer nesse caso?

Exemplo: Eu teria que fazer uma query para jan, fev, mar, abril.. e por ano 2015, 2016, 2017 e ...?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

O código abaixo ira retornar todos os registros que estão entre esse intervalo de datas

```
SELECT suascolunas
FROM sau tabela
WHERE colunaData BETWEEN dataInicio AND dataFinal;
```

Comment: Conheço essa query, a dúvida é como aplicar isso no sistema.
Certamente vou criar dois campos do tipo data para o usuário selecionar o período que deseja, após isso envio as informações digitadas para essa query? Seria isso?

     `SELECT suascolunas

     FROM sau tabela

     WHERE colunaData BETWEEN $dataInicio AND $dataFinal;`

Comment: Só vi agora a mensagem. Isso mesmo, esta correto. Só lembrando que o no sql a data precissa ser assim > 'Y-m-d'

Answer (score 1):

No MySQL tem uma função chamada `Month` que você pode usar para buscar algo de acordo com o mês do ano..

Um exemplo:

```
SELECT nome,endereco
FROM clientes
WHERE Month(data-nascimento) = '06'
```

No código acima fiz um exemplo para buscar uma lista de aniversariantes do mês de Junho.